# Careers: Washington transforms into Washington, DC

Tags: bug, status-deferred, jobs

In Careers - the location Washington, US gets turned into Washington DC. I have to put WA to convert it to the state of Washington. Saving again can corrupt it.

Comment: I've added this to the list of geocode issues.

Comment: When I enter "Washington State" it resolves correctly in the textbox, but when I click "Save" it lists "Washington, DC" in my relocation list.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because Stack Overflow has [discontinued](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/415293) Stack Overflow Jobs and Developer Story on March 31, 2022.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, writing "WA, United States", resolves to Washington correctly. But if you edit the field again, it opens up as "Washington, United States", which is then resolved as Washington DC when saved.

Comment: New York State has the same difficulties, it is resolved as NYC.

Answer (score 2):

It appears that if you enter "Washington State", it will resolve as desired. We depend on Yahoo's geocoding service; what they return is what you see.